# Modal Pop-Up forms for Mobile Browser(Android, iPhone and BlackBerry)

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, blackberry

I need a modal pop up screen/form in my website which should work on Android,iphone and blackberry. I tried using jquery ui dialog for this but it doesn't seem to be working properly on the mentioned devices. Can anybody please help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at jQueryMobile - you can do something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#okButton').bind('click', function () {
        alert('hello world');
    });
</script>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#myDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">Open Dialog</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myDialog" data-role="dialog">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check" id="okButton">OK</a>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-role="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
```